# Unusualy high fail rate with Adafruit Circuit playgrounds

Tags: adafruit

I am on my 4th failed Adafruit Circuit playground, I can usualy program them a few times, like less than 10, then they become unresponsive. no amount of reseting, rebooting, bootloader re-installations, etc seem to help. 
I am using Arduino 1.8.1, on a linux platform, running on a Lenovo T510.

I have numerous other MCUs that have never failed... Im just curious why there is such a high failure rate with the circuit playgrounds I am getting.

Comment: Ask Adafruit?  idk

Comment: Overvoltage somehow? 3.3v Modules with a 5V TTL adapter?